# Regex to Find Second Char is Alpha Followed by 1 numeral

Tags: regex

Regex to Find Second Char is Alpha up to 5 Alpha Followed by 1 numeral.

Thanks

Comment: Try phrasing this in the form of a question, with a few examples of data you'd like to match, and examples of near-matches that you want to reject. We aren't mind readers. If you don't ask good questions, you won't get good (or any) answers, and you'll get downvoted pretty quickly.

Comment: No, need to identify airways that are a specific type.  This has to do with the FAA.  Wish it was home work, but that would be 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I was not successful in implementing any of the solutions above, probably my poor explanation of need.  I did solve it in code not using Regex.  Thanks to everyone who took the time to help.  For those that thought this was homework, it was not.

Here is some sample data.

Need this

I INDY2                      ' INDY VECTOR DP FOR FILING    '041802 REM 59268640 
I JODUB3                     ' AIRWAY FOR JODUB SID         '051205 CLW 59268649

Don't need this

I J149                       '                                      GDK 59265224 
I APE074                     '                                43092 REF 59265777

This is how I tested in code.

```
Dim IsSidStar As Boolean = False
        If aAirways.Name.Length > 2 Then
            Dim a2ndChar As Char = aAirways.Name(1)
            Dim alastChar As Char = aAirways.Name(aAirways.Name.ToString.Length - 1)
            Dim a2ndlastChar As Char = aAirways.Name(aAirways.Name.ToString.Length - 2)

            If Char.IsLetter(a2ndChar) = True AndAlso Char.IsNumber(alastChar) = True AndAlso Char.IsNumber(a2ndlastChar) = False Then
                IsSidStar = True
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.\w{1,5}\d
```

any character followed by between 1 and 5 letters then 1 number

Comment: Yep thats the l33t h4x0r way ;)

Comment: @titaniumdecoy, that is true, not sure what I was thinking

Comment: This one constrains the first character although a constraint is not specified in the question.

Comment: It would only do that if I had used ^\w{1,6}\d which would have specified the beginning of the line, but \w{1,6}\d will match anywhere in the string think of "12lsdfasdfg1" the match here is: asdfg1, however we are left without any information to what the data looks like so we are all just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Double-checking...

- 2nd character is alpha
- up to 5 following alpha (i.e., total 1 - 6 alpha)
- final numeric

Yes?

Assuming first character is irrelevant:

```
/.[A-Za-z]{1,6}\d/
```

Comment: I clarified {1,6} in the checklist. If the "up to 5" includes the first alpha, then it should be {1,5}. But, I read each part as exclusive -- 1 + (0,5) => 1,6

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick.  Regular expression language is .Net implementation

^.[a-zA-Z]{1,5}\d$

Breakdown

- ^ force the match to start at the begining of the text
- . will match anything
- `[a-zA-Z`]`{1,5`} will match any character a-z at least one time but no more than five.  Because of the preceeding "." this means that the match will start at the second character
- \d matches a single digit
- $ matches the end of the text

Comment: The "$" character is a "line end assertion". To get the "line begin assertion", use the "^" character.